# Need help moving contents of one array to another in Irvine Assembly

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86, irvine32

My assignments asks that I generate a random array, move the contents into another array, and then double each value. I'm completely lost on how to copy the array values to the other even though it seems like I need to just move the register contents around.

A snippet of my code to generate the array:

```
     push ebx
     mov ebx, 0
 L1:
     mov eax, 10
     call RandomRange
     inc eax
     mov firArr[ebx], eax
     add ebx, TYPE DWORD
     loop L1

     pop ebx
     ret
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Load from one array into a register, then store from that register into the other array.  (Or use `rep movsb` if that's been covered in your class.  But since you want to copy-and-double, you should load / `add eax,eax` / store instead of copying and then doubling in-place.  The latter would have an extra load/store cycle for all the data.)

Comment: @PeterCordes when I try mov edx, firArr then mov secArr, edx and test it only moves the first array value to the second. I'm trying to figure out how to increment it for the rest of the values.

Comment: You already have a loop that does ` mov firArr[ebx], eax` / `add ebx, TYPE DWORD` to index the array for a store, and increment a byte offset.  Obviously you need to use an index or pointer like you're already doing.